# Search api solr deleted terms showing up in facet

Tags: cron, search

Why would taxonomy terms that I have previously deleted show up in my facet? I'm using search api solr. There is no term named "23"; it is a tid, but tid 23 is not in the database yet my facet shows 29 items as being tagged with it. I have flushed cache, run cron, rebuilt index, all multiple times, and don't know what else to do.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter by that facet and check the nodes that display, they probably still reference the deleted term (see issue: [Database records not deleted for Term Reference Fields after Term is Deleted](https://www.drupal.org/node/1281114))

To get rid of it, edit the nodes and remove the term reference, either manually or programatically depending on the volume.  *Then* reindex your content.

Comment: Thanks for the issue reference. That is it. Removed the offending rows from field_[data,revision]_field_name